# Pyramid: static assets not found

Tags: python, nginx, pyramid

I'm trying to deploy a Pyramid app. My domain is [wisderm.com](http://wisderm.com). The HTML has loaded, but none of the static assets (css, js, images, fonts) are showing up.

In my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` file, I have set the location of the static files as follows, according to [this tutorial](http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deployment/nginx.html):

```
location /static {
  root                    /home/SkinProject; 
                          # this path + /skinproject/static is the absolute 
                          # path to my static directory 
  expires                 30d;
  add_header              Cache-Control public;
  access_log              off;
}
```

In my `__init__.py`, I have added a static view:

```
config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
```

In my HTML templates, I have tried 2 ways of serving static assets:

```
<link href="{{request.static_url('skinproject:static/css/<mycssfile>)}}">
```

for CSS files and plain old relative URLs like `/static/images/products/product_name/01.jpg` for everything else.

Neither way works though. In the Network tab under Chrome Dev Tools, all of the files have a status code of `404 Not Found`.

I took a look at the [Cookbook page on static files](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_cookbook/blob/master/pylons/static.rst), but it seems to be outdated. I also checked the [official documentation about static assets](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/assets.html), but am confused as to whether I should register separate static views for each static directory, e.g.

```
config.add_static_view(name='http://wisderm.com/images', path='skinproject:static/images')
config.add_static_view(name='http://wisderm.com/css', path='skinproject:static/css')
```

What is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't mean to answer my own question, but changing `/static` to `/static/` in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` and making all static urls relative urls worked for me.